# Raspberry Pi - psutil install error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install psutil on my raspberry pi and I cant seem to get to work. If I do pip install I get this error:

```
psutil/_psutil_linux.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import
setuptools;__file__='/home/pi/build/psutil/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n ', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-V39ila-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /home/pi/build/psutil
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

If i try python setup.py build from the directory of the install file I get this error:

```
psutil/_psutil_linux.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

if some one could help me get this installed that would be great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to install the Python development headers too. On Debian (Raspbian “wheezy”), install the `python-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python
```

and get a few more packages that come in handy when compiling Python C extensions.  Replace `python` with `python3` on more recent Debian releases.

On Fedora (Pidora) the equivalent of that last command is:

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-builddep python
```

Here too you may want to replace `python` with `python3` if your system is more recent.

Comment: for `sudo apt-get build-dep python` you will need to make sure there are some source URIs in your sources list.  Otherwise, very nice answer.

Comment: I too got here from troubles on the raspberry pi. This solved my problems there nicely.

Comment: If you have the same issue these days, as I did, you might need to put `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`